# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have been trying to run a program on maven. It is supposed to connect to a jetty server. However I keep getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (default-cli) on project broker-core: The parameters 'executable' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginParameterException
```

I have seen that people had the same problem before, somehow I can't figure out how to fix it though. 
I tried running:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.powertac.samplebroker.core.BrokerMain
```

which started the application, but did not initiate any communication between the server and the program.

```
mvn exec:exec -Dexec.mainClass=org.powertac.samplebroker.core.BrokerMain
```

which gave me the error message above.

I tried running it from within the Spring. It didn't change anything. I also tried just

```
mvn exec:exec
```

which also didn't work.

The pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>broker-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Common core of a Power TAC broker implementation</description>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>broker-core</name>
  <url>http://www.powertac.org</url>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.powertac</groupId>
<artifactId>server-master</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
<relativePath />

</parent>
      <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>    

<active-mq.version>5.7.0</active-mq.version>
<xbean-spring.version>4.5</xbean-spring.version>
<jopt-simple.version>4.9</jopt-simple.version>
<json-lib.version>2.4</json-lib.version>
<commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>

<aspectj-rt.version>1.8.7</aspectj-rt.version>
<aspectj-plugin.version>1.8</aspectj-plugin.version>
<aspectj-plugin.compliance>1.8</aspectj-plugin.compliance>
```

```
  <!-- Sonatype OSS repo for resolving snapshot modules -->
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
</repository>
```

```
  <dependencies>    
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- ActiveMQ -->
<dependency>    
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
  <version>${active-mq.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>    
  <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
  <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
  <version>${active-mq.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
  <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
  <version>${xbean-spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.jopt-simple</groupId>
  <artifactId>jopt-simple</artifactId>
  <version>${jopt-simple.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>   
  <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>   
  <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>   
  <version>${json-lib.version}</version>   
  <classifier>jdk15</classifier>   
</dependency>
<dependency>   
  <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
  <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

```
  <build>
<finalName>broker-core</finalName>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>${maven-compiler.source}</source>
      <target>${maven-compiler.target}</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>test-compile</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <verbose>false</verbose>
          <complianceLevel>${aspectj-plugin.compliance}</complianceLevel>
          <weaveDependencies>
            <weaveDependency>
              <groupId>org.powertac</groupId>
              <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            </weaveDependency>
          </weaveDependencies>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>

      <!--  bundle sources for javadoc prep -->
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>bundle-sources</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <!-- produce source artifact for main project sources -->
          <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
  </build>

  <scm>
<connection>scm:git:git//github.com/powertac/broker-core.git</connection>
<developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:powertac/broker-core.git</developerConnection>
<url>https://github.com/powertac</url>
```

Comment: you should provide the error log message as well, so people can help.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I added it! @Vijay

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you are missing `executable` in your mvn command.  And you should also add the exec plugin to plugins sections as specified in the [maven usage section](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html)

and update the exec plugin's configuration section as

```
        <configuration>
      <executable>java</executable>
      <arguments>
        <argument>-Dmyproperty=myvalue</argument>
        <argument>-classpath</argument>
        <!-- automatically creates the classpath using all project dependencies,
             also adding the project build directory -->
        <classpath/>
        <argument>org.powertac.samplebroker.core.BrokerMain</argument>
        ...
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
```

refer: http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html

And then Try `mvn exec:exec -Dexec.executable="java"`

Comment: It still gives me the same error message. Although I do get more information about options in java now. @vijay